# pytest: Why is my mocked function not called

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm only now starting with pytest, have some experience with cpputest. Mocking in pytest is very hard for me to understand. For example, I don't understand why the mocked function `a.ab` is not called here:

I have a.py which just defines a little function:

```
"""Some module, defines something."""
import logging


def ab(a, b):
    logging.debug("a,b :{}".format(a, b))
```

Then I have a dut.py, which calls `a.ab`:

```
"""Module that uses a.ab"""

import logging
from a import ab


class Dut():
    """Device (code) under test
    """

    def run(self):
        logging.debug("ab: {}".format(ab))
        ab("a", "b")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG")
    dut = Dut()
    dut.run()
```

Now I'd like to test that `ab("a", "b")` is really called. That's my test:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
from dut import Dut


def test_run_ab(monkeypatch):
    mock_a = Mock()
    monkeypatch.setattr('dut.ab', mock_a)
    dut = Dut()
    dut.run()

    # mock_a.ab("a", "b")
    mock_a.ab.assert_called_with("a", "b")
```

That's the result of the test run (with loggin enabled in pytest.ini):

```
test_dut.py::test_run_ab 
------------------------------------ live log call  -----------------------------------
dut.py                      12 DEBUG    ab: <Mock id='47533802232072'> FAILED                                                                          [100%]

====================================== FAILURES =======================================
___________________________________ test_run_ab ____________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x2b3b536597f0>

    def test_run_ab(monkeypatch):
        mock_a = Mock()
        monkeypatch.setattr('dut.ab', mock_a)
        dut = Dut()
        dut.run()

        # mock_a.ab("a", "b")
>       mock_a.ab.assert_called_with("a", "b")

test_dut.py:13: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

_mock_self = <Mock name='mock.ab' id='47533802232464'>, args = ('a', 'b'), kwargs = {}
expected = "ab('a', 'b')"

    def assert_called_with(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs):
        """assert that the mock was called with the specified arguments.

            Raises an AssertionError if the args and keyword args passed in are
            different to the last call to the mock."""
        self = _mock_self
        if self.call_args is None:
            expected = self._format_mock_call_signature(args, kwargs)
>           raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' %     (expected,))
E           AssertionError: Expected call: ab('a', 'b')
E           Not called

/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py:785: AssertionError
---------------------------------- Captured log call ----------------------------------
dut.py                      12 DEBUG    ab: <Mock id='47533802232072'>
============================== 1 failed in 0.09 seconds ===============================
```

The logging in `dut.run` (line 12) shows me that I managed to patch the `ab` function in dut.py. The logging output is: `dut.py                      12 DEBUG    ab: <Mock id='47533802232072'>`, so it is at least not the original function.

If I uncomment the direct call to `mock_a.ab("a", "b")`, the test passes (well, no surprise).

I really don't get my mistake.

Comment: Why do you test `mock_a.ab.assert_called`? `mock_a` is a replacement for `dut.ab`, so `mock_a.ab` is effectively `dut.ab.ab`. Check `mock_a.assert_called` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I had tomatoes on my eyes...

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us :)